# Array sum and count row in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum, array-sum

I have a function getData that returns:

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5689.01"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5689.01"

  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "0.0"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5665.11"
   ]
]
```

I need to COUNT number of rows (this time 4, as above) with values that are returned every time when I trigger a call and return total SUM of all results as listed.

```
 $rows = $this->get('app')->getData();

 if($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $sumOfAll = 0;
            $total = count($rows);
            $sumOfAll += array_sum(array($row[0] * $total));

            dump($sumOfAll);die;
    }
}
```

I always get a wrong sum, in this case it was 22756.04.

Comment: `$sumOfAll = array_sum(array_column($rows, 6))*count($rows);`

Comment: @splash58 `6` where do you get that from?

Comment: It the same as your last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361937/sum-all-returned-row-values-php) please avoid this - if the last not relevant remove it

Comment: I should have edit it. Thanks. @dWinder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array_sum and array_column to get the values and sum them.
Then use count() to get the count.

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($arr, 0));
$count = count($arr);

echo "count is ". $count . " And sum is " . $sum;
```

https://3v4l.org/HFbgc

Answer (score 0):

To fix your sum value, you need to move `$sumOfAll` variable out side of your `foreach`

Change your code from this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sumOfAll = 0;
    $total = count($rows);
    $sumOfAll += array_sum(array($row[6] * $total));

    dump($sumOfAll);die;
}
```

to this:

```
$sumOfAll = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $total = count($rows);
    $sumOfAll += array_sum(array($row[6] * $total));
}
dump($sumOfAll);die;
```